# How to write a long \rightharpoonup?

Tags: arrows, xrightarrow

How to write a long `$\rightharpoonup$` with the possibility to write something above and below the arrow.

I need to write below `$k \to +\infty$`, so the `$\rightharpoonup$` must be as long as `$k \to +\infty$`.

Comment: Also see [How to look up a symbol or identify a letter from a math alphabet or other character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/5764) for other options (including extensible ones).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mathtools` defines a couple of extensible symbols in addition to the kernel and `amsmath` defined ones:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
$\xrightharpoonup{k\to+\infty}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

or if the label should be below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
$a \xrightharpoonup[k\to+\infty]{} b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

(In general `\xrightharpoonup[below]{above}`.)